# I want to switch screens after user inactivity

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

you know some way to create a type of protection screen for the app.
I want the app to return to a certain screen after a certain period of inactivity.

in flutter

Comment: Flutter has a Timer class which you can look into if you want to implement this feature

Comment: but with this class I can't tell if the user is touching the screen or not

Comment: You will have to handle that yourself. Or look into some third party library that does what you want.

Comment: Do you know any library?